# How to get three words to show up spaced out?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'd like for the end result to look something like this:

> Certain [A bunch of space] Neutral [A bunch of space] Uncertain

where the twp bunches of space are equal, and where the full line takes up the width of the page.

What I've tried is `Certain \hfill Uncertain,` but I can't seem to get the word "Neutral" centered. I'm trying to stay away from hard-coding it and using the `verbatim` environment.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You say you want the word "Neutral" centered.  That is different from wanting the intervening spaces to be the same width.  `\hfill` will result in equal spaces, but if you want the middle word centered, you have to think of the line as being in two parts, each in a box the width of the line: the first is `{Certain\hfill Uncertain}`; the second is `{\hfill Neutral\hfill}`; and the two  are set "overlapped": `\rlap{<first>}{<second>}`.  (Actually the order doesn't matter.)  I'm not able to test, so this is just a description of what needs to be done.

Comment: There are several approaches, but which one I would suggest would depend on why you want the words to be spaced out.  Are you trying to make these the top of a table?  Or are you wanting an otherwise blank page that brainstormers will write on?  Or something else?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm trying to caption a Tikz image. It's an image of a spectrum, and I want the ends and middle to be labeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Something like this? (The frame lines are there just to indicate the edges of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show edges of text block
\begin{document}
\noindent
Certain \hfill Neutral \hfill Uncertain\par
\end{document}
```

TeXnically speaking, with this setup, the word "Neutral" is not guaranteed to be *centered exactly* on the page. It's the amount of whitespace on either side of the word that's guaranteed to be equal. However, unless the first and third words are quite different in length, nobody but an exceedingly vigilant copy editor will notice that "Neutral" isn't centered exactly on the line.

In order to fully guarantee that the middle word is, in fact, centered on the line, irrespective of the lengths of the first and third words, you would need to write

```
\noindent
\parbox{0.33333\linewidth}{Certain}%
\parbox{0.33333\linewidth}{\centering Neutral}%
\parbox{0.33333\linewidth}{\hfill Uncertain}
```

Only you can decide if your typesetting needs justify the additional overhead.

Comment: You can also use `\noindent\rlap{Certain}\hfill Neutral\hfill\llap{Uncertain}` to center `Neutral` precisely.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show edges of text block
\begin{document}
\noindent
{Certain Neutral Uncertain\parfillskip=0pt\par}

foo bar
\end{document}
```

[image]